# adding view to linear layout not visible

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a problem adding programmatically buttons to linearLayout, the first button gets added but the others aren't visible.

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //show or load next

                Button curButton = new Button(myClass.this);
                curButton.setText("" + text);
                curButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tran_mini);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                curButton.setLayoutParams(params);

                curButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0)
                    {
                        //do smg
                    }
                });

                paginglibrary.addView(curButton);
       }
 });
```

this is the xml file where the buttons are being added:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pagingView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

the first time I click on nextButton the button gets added and is show but the second time I add another button, it doesn't show.
I am sure they are getting added as I checked through the following code:

```
 ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.pagingView1);
 System.out.println("layout count: "+ layout.getChildCount());
```

the count shows that the button is getting added but it's not showing.
Any idea what could be the cause?

I tried setting the abscissa of the button to make sure it's not being outside of the view but still the same scenario occurs.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the `LinearLayout` to be `vertical`?

Comment: Yes I want the buttons to be added horizontally

Comment: OK, well, you've got that `ScrollView`'s width set at `150dp`. How wide are your `Button`s ending up? Btw, `ScrollView` scrolls vertically only.

Comment: since the`LinearLayout` adds horizontally try increasing the parent view group (`ScrollView`) width.

Comment: you are right about scrollview, I guess I should use horizontalScrollView, but even without the scrollView, it still doesn't work and the button is no more than 30 px, so it should fit at least 5 buttons

Comment: As mentioned before I also tried to setX for curButton before adding it or even after adding it, to put it for example 60, but still it wouldn't show, kindly note that the background of the button is transparent, therefore is they were behind each other it should show.

Comment: i kinda tried to reproduce it. I managed to see the buttons and scroll through them when i set the `HorizontalScrollView` width 'wrap_content'

Comment: ok will try that

Comment: @StamatisStiliats you were right, would you kindly write it as an answer so I may accept it, thank you for your help.

Comment: it even works with 150dp width of HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="new button"/>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pagingView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The only difference is on the `HorizontalScrollView` width.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //show or load next

                Button curButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                curButton.setText("generated button");

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                curButton.setLayoutParams(params);

                curButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0)
                    {
                        //do smg
                    }
                });

                ll.addView(curButton);
            }
        });
```